# How to select a log analytics workspace in azure monitor notebook using a parameter?

Tags: azure-monitor-workbooks, azure-monitor

I would like to have the user select the log analytics workspace as a parameter in an Azure Monitor notebook to perform a query, similar to what is explained in the [parameter documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/Application-Insights-Workbooks/blob/master/Documentation/Parameters/Resources.md). However, I can't resolve the log analytics workspace using a variable.

What I would like to do is something like:

```
let event_table = workspace({parameter}).Event;
event_table
| take 5
```

The following query using a string literal is successful in both an azure monitor notebook and in a log query:

```
let event_table = workspace("name_of_work_space").Event;
event_table
| take 5
```

The following fails with the error `"Unknown function 'workspace'.` in both an azure monitor notebook and a log query:

```
let logAnalyticsWorkspaceName = "name_of_work_space";
let event_table = workspace(logAnalyticsWorkspaceName).Event;
event_table
| take 5
```

It seems that only string literals are allowed as arguments to the `workspace()` function.

Additionally, `iff()` and `case()` functions only return scalars so I cannot use `iff()` and `case()` to conditionally return a table or workspace based on a Azure Notebook parameter.

How do I supply a parameter to an Azure Monitor Notebook to query against a particular log analytics workspace?

Comment: you *can* use the parameter syntax like you have, you just need quotes `workspace("{parameter}").Event` .  but it is better to use a resource parameter and target the entire query at the workspace instead of adjusting the workspace in the query text, if you can avoid it

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically setting the workspace be accomplished using a parameter. Create a parameter for Workspaces where the parameter type is Resource picker (from Azure Resource Graph). That parameter will then appear as an option in the Log Analytics drop down for downstream controls. A demonstration appears in the video "[How to build tabs and alerts in Azure workbooks | Azure Portal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XY3lYgrRvA)" at 5:00.